# IOS Objective C save image that is displayed in UIWebview by press and hold like in Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a beginner by IOS. I'm programming an app that display a website within UIWebview. Now I want that when the user press and hold on an image, he then can save the image like in safari. my code looks like this right now, but the app can not even recognize the press and hold gesture:

```
    -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
else if([request.URL.absoluteString containsString:@".png"]||[request.URL.absoluteString containsString:@".jpg"]){
            self.lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPressGestures:)];

            self.lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0f;
            self.lpgr.allowableMovement = 100.0f;
            self.lpgr.delegate = self;

            [self.webVIew addGestureRecognizer:self.lpgr];


        return false;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

- (void)handleLongPressGestures:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"go within LongPressgesture methode");
    if ([sender isEqual:self.lpgr]) {
       if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
       {
           NSLog(@"go within LongPressgesture methode2");

            UIMenuItem* myBtn1 = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Speichern" action:@selector( onButton1: )];

            UIMenuController* mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
            mc.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myBtn1, nil];

                }


    }
    }
- (void) onButton1: (UIMenuController*) sender
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.webVIew.frame.size);
    [self.webVIew.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self, nil, nil);

}
 and in the header file:
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIButton *btnHome;

    BOOL isLoaded;
    ACAccountStore *account ;


}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks for every advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebView already has a gesture recognizer. Therefore you need to implement the method `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer` of the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. Otherwise the touch is only send to the gesture recognizer of the web view.

Therefore add the following method to your code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Add this protocol to your header: `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

And when creating your gesture recognizer add the following line:

```
self.lpgr.delegate = self;
```